# Variable declaration inside a loop

Tags: java

One common dilemma I have faced throughout programming is regarding declaring variables inside a loop. Say I have to perform something like the following:

```
List list=myObject.getList();
Iterator itr=list.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()){
    BusinessObject myBo=(BusinessObject)itr.next();
    process(myBo);
}
```

In the above snippet, should `myBo` be declared outside the loop or does declaring it inside the loop not cause harm to memory and performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myBo` is simply a reference to an object (that is returned by itr.next()). As such the amount of memory that it needs is very small, and only created once, and adding it inside the loop should not affect your program. IMO, declaring it inside the loop where it is used actually helps make it more readable.

Comment: This answer is misleading, as it implies that the reference-variable is allocated once each iteration, which is *not* true.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: As I said in my answer, it is merely creating a *reference* to an object, not allocating the whole object itself. That is why the amount of memory is very small - because only the few bytes needed for the reference is all that is involved.

Comment: Yes I understand; but even that reference (the pointer itself) is only allocated once, which is counter to what the phrase *"allocating/deallocating it should not affect your program significantly"* is implying.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: I see now that it might be misread. Changing my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 8):

Declaring it inside the loop won't cause any harm to the memory and performance.

Answer (score 5):

If possible use `List<BusinessObject>` and `Iterator<BusinessObject>` to avoid casting:

```
List<BusinessObject> list = myObject.getList();
Iterator<BusinessObject> itr = list.iterator();

while (itr.hasNext()) {
   process(itr.next());
}
```

Comment: That of course only works in 1.5 and higher. Not everyone is so fortunate :)

Answer (score 5):

One principle of good software design is to limit the scope of local variables, i.e. to declare them just in time within a block that ends soon after the last use of that variable. This doesn't affect performance or other "hard" aspects but makes the program more readable and easier to analyze.

In summary, doing what you're doing is considered GOOD.

Answer (score 4):

The most elegant solution for your loop would be an enhanced for loop (java 5 or newer):

```
List<BusinessObject> list = myObject.getList();

for( BusinessObject myBo : list ) {
    process(myBo);
}
```

But even with the code you provided there will be no performance problem, because all the temporary variables only hold references to the **BusinessObject**, which is very cheap.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't cause any memory harm.

BTW unless you're omitting some code you may skip the declaration altogether:

```
while (itr.hasNext()){
    //BusinessObject myBo=(BusinessObject)itr.next();
    process((BusinessObject)itr.next());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If short -- no.
In C++ it could be a problem if myBo is created by copying
but in Java there is always used references, is'nt it?
for performance, its better to optimize something you are do in process()

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at the byte code with `javap -c [ClassName]`. Here's a class demonstrating a few examples of single-use variables with loops. The relevant bytecode dump is in the comments:

```
class HelloWorldLoopsAnnotated {
    //
    // HelloWorldLoopsAnnotated();
    //   Code:
    //    0:   aload_0
    //    1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
    //    4:   return
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    void stringDeclaredInsideLoop(){
        while (true) {
            // 0:   ldc #2; //String Hello World!
            String greeting = "Hello World!";
            doNothing(greeting);
        }
    }
    //
    // void stringDeclaredInsideLoop();
    //   Code:
    //    0:   ldc #2; //String Hello World!
    //    2:   astore_1
    //    3:   aload_0
    //    4:   aload_1
    //    5:   invokespecial   #3; //Method doNothing:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    //    8:   goto    0
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    void stringDeclaredOutsideLoop(){
        String greeting;
        while (true) {
            greeting = "Hello World!";
            doNothing(greeting);
        }
    }
    //
    // void stringDeclaredOutsideLoop();
    //   Code:
    //    0:   ldc #2; //String Hello World!
    //    2:   astore_1
    //    3:   aload_0
    //    4:   aload_1
    //    5:   invokespecial   #3; //Method doNothing:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    //    8:   goto    0
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    void stringAsDirectArgument(){
        while (true) {
            doNothing("Hello World!");
        }
    }
    // void stringAsDirectArgument();
    //   Code:
    //    0:   aload_0
    //    1:   ldc #2; //String Hello World!
    //    3:   invokespecial   #3; //Method doNothing:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    //    6:   goto    0
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private void doNothing(String s) {
    }
}
```

`stringDeclaredInsideLoop()` and `stringDeclaredOutsideLoop()` yield identical six-instruction bytecode. `stringDeclaredInsideLoop()` does still win: *limited scope is best*.

After some contemplation, I can't really see how tightening scope would ever affect performance: identical data in the stack would necessitate identical instructions.

`stringAsDirectArgument()`, however, defines the operation in only four instructions. Low memory environments (e.g. my magnificently dumb phone) may appreciate the optimization while a colleague reading your code may not, so exercise judgement before shaving bytes from your code.

See the [full gist](https://gist.github.com/3694560) for more.

Answer (score 0):

The temporary reference `myBo` is put on stack and should mostly be optimized away. There shouldn't be any performance penalty in your code.